# Sending batch rest api request from apex

Tags: rest-api, batch, rest, httprequest

I need to get multiple data from salesforce. To get the resource i call the endpoint as shown below.

```
public String getData(Id docId) {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(baseURL + '/services/data/v42.0/connect/files/+'docId');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
        request.setHeader('X-Connect-Bearer-Urls', 'true');

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
     }
String data1 = getData(abcdef);
String data2 = getData(lklsdk);
```

Now, Instead of calling getData() method twice and calling the rest endpoint twice, i am  trying to use batch rest api.

SO, i changed the endpoint as:

```
request.setEndpoint(baseURL + '/services/data/v42.0/connect/files/batch/+docId1+','+docId2);
```

Unfortunately, when i run the send the above request, I get invalid session Id issue but if i call the endpoint multiple times by removing batch *(as shown in above function)*, i get correct response.

So, how do i resolve send multiple ids using batch rest api?

Comment: I may not have understood this completely, but curious - why do you want to call a REST API from within an Apex to be able to retrieve records, as what is your use case here? If you are well within force.com's  context, you can directly query based on the Id. Is this something that you are looking to implement somewhere outside Salesforce, as in a web client or so?

Comment: Yes, I can query it but i am interested in the  json response that will be sent by the server. In the JSON response, there are some extra key value pairs that i need.

Comment: I was able to get values of multiple files by passing the ids the way you have here (*connect/files/batch/id1,id2*).  Have you tried getting a new token and trying it again?

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks, probably that is the case. I had to clear all chrome history, caches e.t.c. I waslogged into salesforce in chrome and i got the above error but when i logged into salesforce using mozilla, no error was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rolling up comment to an answer if it helps someone in similar situation.**

I tried getting details of multiple files using the API mentioned in the question and was able to successfully get response. My request url looked like:

```
https://myinstance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/connect/files/batch/xxxid1,yyyid2
```

Using a stale access token, I received invalid session id as expected.

```
[
    {
        "message": "Session expired or invalid",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
    }
]
```

However, when I tried with a new access token, I was able to get the response (sample response below, removed all other details).

```
{
"hasErrors": false,
"results": [
    {
        "result": {
            "downloadUrl": "/services/data/v42.0/connect/files/xxxid1/content?versionNumber=1",
            "id": "xxxid1",
        },
        "statusCode": 200
    },
    {
        "result": {
            "downloadUrl": "/services/data/v42.0/connect/files/yyyid2/content?versionNumber=1",
            "id": "yyyid2",
        },
        "statusCode": 200
    }
]
}
```

Based on your comment above:

> I had to clear all chrome history, caches e.t.c. I waslogged into salesforce in chrome and i got the above error but when i logged into salesforce using mozilla, no error was thrown

The root cause here seemed to be the access token. Using the correct access token worked fine.